# Reducing size of a pandas database by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset with multiple columns that have various dates and data. I want to create a new database restricting on a date range for hundreds of different columns.

```
toy = pd.DataFrame()
toy['Date1'] = ['4/12/2020','4/11/2020','4/10/2020']
toy['Data1'] = [1, 2, 3]

toy['Date2'] = ['4/13/2020', '4/11/2020', '4/09/2020']
toy['Data2'] = [4, 5, 6]
```

New database, where the "Date" column is specified or taken from one of the toy Dates:

```
new = pd.DataFrame()
new['Date'] = ['4/11/2020', '04/09/2020', '3/31/2020']
new['Data1'] = [2, NaN, NaN]
new['Data2'] = [5, 6, NaN]
```

Realize this is really simple but need something that can work for hundreds of columns and don't want to use loops necessarily.

Comment: Do you mean `toy['Date2']` in your first toy dataframe?

Comment: How many rows does your dataframe have?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a non-loop way to do this, however, you can try unifying the index of the initial dataframe by having all dates in the index so at least the number of interations is reduced. This can be done by a process, first, let's add an additional column:

```
toy['Date10'] = ['4/12/2020', '4/11/2020', '4/20/2020']
toy['Data10'] = [2, 8, 7]

toy.columns # ['Date1', 'Data1', 'Date2', 'Data2', 'Date10', 'Data10']
```

Create a list of dataframes where each of the elements contains the pair `Date-Data` and set `Date` as the index, then `concat`

```
import re

dfs_toy = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]).dropna()
   for i, x in toy.groupby(lambda x: re.split('([0-9]+)', x)[1], axis=1)]

toy_2 = pd.concat(dfs_toy, axis=1)

#           Data1  Data10  Data2
# 4/12/2020 1.0    2.0     NaN
# 4/11/2020 2.0    8.0     5.0
# 4/10/2020 3.0    NaN     NaN
```

Finally, if you create a new data frame with a different index, just assign all the columns and if there is match the column will be assigned othrwise `nan` values will be assigned:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=['4/12/2020', '4/10/2020', '4/25/2020'])
new_df[toy_2.columns] = toy_2
new_df.head()

#            Data1 Data10 Data2
# 4/12/2020  1.0   2.0    NaN
# 4/10/2020  3.0   NaN    NaN
# 4/25/2020  NaN   NaN    NaN
```